# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in controller#method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am doing complex search, and for that I have special model:

```
create_table "cmdb_searches", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "client"
  t.string   "in"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

and method search inside evms_controller:

```
def search
  @cisearch = CmdbSearch.new(search_params)
  @evms = Evm.order('id DESC')
  @evms = @evms.where('client_name=?',@cisearch.client) if #cisearch.client.present?
  @evms = @evms.where('in=?',@cisearch.in) if @cisearch.in.present?
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

and my js file fills the apropriate div with the response. It works if I leave form empty or fill only :client field, BUT if i fill :in field it will return me an error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near "in": syntax error: SELECT "evms".* FROM "evms" WHERE (in='234543')  ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`in` is an SQL operator](http://webcheatsheet.com/sql/interactive_sql_tutorial/sql_in.php). While technically you can use it as a column name, to do so, you have to escape it. And that's why I try to avoid using plain SQL in my queries.

Replace `@evms.where('in=?',@cisearch.in)` with `@evms.where(in: @cisearch.in)`. That way it will be escaped properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can not name your column `in`. Because this is reserved keyword in SQLite, and it will generate errors as it is causing right now.

Answer (score 2):

[`in`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) is a reserved keyword. That's why SQLite or any DBMS which has `in` as its one of the keywords, will throw this error. I'd recommend you to change the column name to something else, for example `within`. Otherwise you'll have to make sure you escape(quote:``) it all the time in your queries.

Answer (score 1):

`in` is a reserved word in sql. You have to quote it so it is taken as a column name.

Using standard arel notation would be properly quoted

```
where(:in => @cisearch.in)
```

or quoting it manually with the backtick

`` where("`in` = ?",@cisearch.in) ``